# Running a React-Router Site on Basic Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, react-router

I may have a basic misunderstanding of how things work, so bear with me.

### Project

I have built a small website with NPM, Webpack, React, and react-router. the site has six content-only pages generated by react components. Each page is served up through react router, meaning I can go to localhost:8080/page-2 directly and be given the page I mean to display at that page.

### Issue

It works well, but the problem is I can only get it to work while running a server locally, set up using the technique described [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uextYhQGP6k&index=2&list=PL55RiY5tL51oyA8euSROLjMFZbXaV7skS)

I tried running the site with [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) to see if I could pass my project off to my client to run on whatever server he runs this on. This needs to be a pretty hands-off launch, but my fear is that my client's server needs to be of a certain type, or need to be configured in a specific way.

I understand I may have built this incorrectly. Is there a good way to build React(with react-router) sites in the future so that launching is a simple drag-and-drop process?

Answer (score -1):

**Issue**

The thing causing your issue is the react-router. If you don't use any routing, the server gives you index.html and then with react (javascript) you handle any static or dynamic content you wish.
  When you use react-router for routing, it pushes new URL into your browser every time a link is clicked. The server has no idea that you run a client(browser) app and tries to go into this url/directory specified. 
  That means that any form of launch you choose, it must either take care of it or you must specify to the server that it needs to serve `index.html`, whatever the current url is. There are many ways to do that, for example in my Node app, I have:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});
```

**Summary**

The server doesn't know it's a client app. It tries to serve you files/urls that doesn't exist. You must tell it to serve `index.html` at all times.